# Xcode iOS7 Tabbar custom font question marks

Tags: fonts, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, custom-font

> Hi there,
>
> I'm building an app with a custom font. I imported the font into the
>   'Supporting Files' group and added it to the .plist file. When running
>   the simulator the text shows questions marks. If I change
>   'fontWithName:@"XBANDRough”' with other fonts like
>   'AmericanTypewriter' it does work right. I also tried this with
>   another font but the same happened. It would be great if you could
>   help me.
>
> Luuk

This was in the log when searching all fonts:

```
2013-11-23 23:34:45.056 Wie Is De Mol? 2014[25632:70b] XBAND Rough
2013-11-23 23:34:45.056 Wie Is De Mol? 2014[25632:70b]   XBANDRough
```

TabBarViewController.h:

```
@interface TabBarViewController : UITabBarController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *TabBar;

@end
```

TabBarViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //tabbar custom font (XBAND Rough)
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"XBANDRough" size:10.0f],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1]
                                                        } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**Images:**
http://imgur.com/a/ViEJ0

This is the font: http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-XBAND+Rough

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if Xcode is corrupting your font files

1. Right click the font in Xcode and show in finder.
2. Right click font, get info.
3. Does the preview of the font display correctly? If not, herein lies
       your problem.
4. Does your project name contain special chars? (?><,! etc)

Xcode doesn't play too nicely with project names that contain special characters, try creating a new project with an alphanumeric name.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the correct font name. Right click on the font and have it show in the finder. Once you're in the finder use CMD + i to see more information about the font and then look at the full name section.

Full Name: "Should be the full name of your font"

Also see this link: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/